# How to disable Xbox 360 "no connection" nag?

Tags: xbox-360

[image: off-screen shot]

Whenever Xbox 360 is started or swithing accounts the console displays a message which the user must dismiss by selecting "no" if no internet connection is available. My 360 is nearly completely offline, I connect only a couple of times a year  to download updates for disc-based gamed. Router Wi-fi doesn't carry to the TV room (and I'm not rewiring my house), even though my phone is always able to connect.

The error message was either added in the most recent Dashboard update or is exclusive to the new "Slim" model.
I've even considered downgrading the OS, but that may require modding the console and likely gets its serial number and accounts banned from Xbox Live.

Comment: Are there any networks nearby that it can connect to? Open/free networks, or ones it has connected to before?